# Trying to draw rectangles on click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I've been self teaching c# and following tutorials. Up until this time there was no major problems. Bun now i cant find solution on my own.

So i got a listing of a simple form that's supposed to create rectangles and attractor points on different mouse clicks. But when I run the code, nothing happens.

I cant understand what is wrong.. please help (=

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    float mRectSize = 50;
    List<RectangleF> mRectangles = new List<RectangleF>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    PointF mForcePoint = new PointF(-1, -1);
    bool mForcePush = false;
    int mRandomSeed = 10;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 1;
        timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
        timer1.Start();


    }

    private void AddRectangle(PointF pos)
    {

        mRectangles.Add(new RectangleF(pos.X - mRectSize / 2, pos.Y - mRectSize / 2, mRectSize, mRectSize));
    }

    private void AddForcePoint(PointF pos)
    {
        mForcePoint = pos;
    }

    private void DrawRectangle(Graphics g, RectangleF rect)
    {
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255));
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c), rect);
    }

    private PointF RandomiseDirection(PointF dir)
    {
        dir.X += rnd.Next(2 * mRandomSeed) - mRandomSeed;
        dir.Y += rnd.Next(2 * mRandomSeed) - mRandomSeed;

        return dir;
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        foreach (RectangleF rect in mRectangles)
        {
            DrawRectangle(g, rect);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            AddRectangle(e.Location);
            //MessageBox.Show("test");
            Invalidate();
        }

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            AddForcePoint(e.Location);
        }

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle)
        {
            mForcePush = !mForcePush;
        }

    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mForcePoint.X != -1 && mForcePoint.Y != -1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mRectangles.Count; i++)
            {
                RectangleF rect = mRectangles[i];

                PointF direction = new PointF(mForcePoint.X - rect.Location.X, mForcePoint.Y - rect.Location.Y);

                direction = RandomiseDirection(direction);

                if (mForcePush)
                {
                    rect.Location = new PointF(rect.Location.X - direction.X * 0.1f, rect.Location.Y - direction.Y * 0.1f);
                }

                else
                {
                    rect.Location = new PointF(rect.Location.X + direction.X * 0.1f, rect.Location.Y + direction.Y * 0.1f);
                }

                mRectangles[i] = rect;

            }

            Invalidate();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This seems like a good time to learn about debugging. Try setting some breakpoints and see what's going on.

Comment: Is mForcePoint ever being changed?

Comment: Its suppose to change on pressing RMB.. but still nothing.

Comment: When I originally tried to test your code, I forgot to hook up the Paint event, which to me made it look like the UI wasn't drawing due to a saturated message queue. But that's not actually the problem at all. In fact, the code works fine for me, once all the events are subscribed. So, lacking a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, all I can say is go check to make sure your events are all subscribed like you think they should be. Set breakpoints in each of the event handlers and make sure they're called when they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was simple. And I blame a tutorial, since there was no mention of this what's so ever.

I just needed to add 
MouseClick += (name of my MouseClick method)
To 
Private Form1 ()